# Updating the (GC) Garbage Collection policy of IBM Websphere (WAS) v8

Tags: java, garbage-collection, websphere

We have a Java EE application that runs on Websphere (IBM WebSphere Application Server v8.5.5.1)

According to IBM (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1106_bailey/1106_bailey.html), the default GC policy of WAS v8 is `-Xgcpolicy:gencon`

I need to change this default to `-Xgcpolicy:balanced`

I have searched online and here on stackoverflow but haven't found any instruction how I can achieve this.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

That's just a JVM property.  Have you tried setting that JVM argument in the WAS Admin console?

Middleware servers > server-name > Process definition > Java Virtual Machine

And of course do a save/synch and stop/start of the server to pick up the changes.

Comment: (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21417365 -- first hit when websearching "websphere java options")